# In Android Hardware Keyboard, pressing Space bar causes Ctrl key releasing

Tags: android

I try using Hardware Keyboard in my Android App, If I'm holding the Ctrl Key (ACTION_DOWN) and then pressing the Space bar, the Ctrl Key is automatically released (ACTION_UP)

```
2023-07-13 17:02:06.398   Down Ctrl
2023-07-13 17:02:06.433   Down Ctrl
2023-07-13 17:02:06.439   Up Ctrl
2023-07-13 17:02:06.840   Down Space
```

In the Log above

- **Down Ctrl** is when I'm holding the Ctrl key
- **Up Ctrl** and **Down Space** is when I press the Space bar

As you can see, the Ctrl Key is released (ACTION_UP) automatically when I press the Space bar, and then when I actually release the Ctrl Key, the Key up event is triggered again.
Here is the code I use for testing

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Log.d("test-key", "Down " + getKeyName(event.getKeyCode()));
    }

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        Log.d("test-key", "Up " + getKeyName(event.getKeyCode()));
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Why does that happen?